# How can I toggle displaying images in eww without a page refresh?

Tags: images, eww

I use eww to browse the internet and more often than not I do not want images to load, there doesn't seem to be much in terms of customizations built in for eww and none dealing with images.

Currently I have a system setup that allows me to start and stop showing images in eww but only after a page refresh, what I want is a way to toggle images on and off **without refreshing the page**.

Here is my current method which takes advantage of the internals of `shr-put-image` which eww uses.

```
(defvar display-graphic-override nil
  "Used to override `display-graphic-p' behavior.
Should either be nil, or a list where the car is the override.")

(defadvice display-graphic-p (around sometimes-lie activate)
  "Use the override if it is non nil."
  (if display-graphic-override
      (car display-graphic-override)
    ad-do-it))

(defadvice eww-render (around no-images activate)
  "Temporarily lie about supporting graphics"
  (let ((display-graphic-override '(nil)))
    ad-do-it))
```

I have also tried toggling the 'invisible text property where images are but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Background

Eww, as many other packages, uses the `display` text property to
display images. That is why toggling the `invisible` text property
didn’t help. You’re making the text itself invisible but the `display`
property is still being shown.

In fact, this is something so common that the code below should work
on any buffer that displays images (not just eww).

### Solution

The easiest solution is to just remove the `display` property from the
entire buffer. But that’s an irreversible action, you wouldn’t be able
to turn images back on without refreshing the page.

The more robust solution, presented below, removes `display`
properties in the buffer and simultaneously backs-up the image to
another (useless) property. When called again, the command moves the
backed up images back into the `display` property.

```
(defvar-local endless/display-images t)

(defun endless/toggle-image-display ()
  "Toggle images display on current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (setq endless/display-images
        (null endless/display-images))
  (endless/backup-display-property endless/display-images))
```

This is the guy who does the backup and restore everywhere. Text
property code isn’t terribly easy to read, but I think this function
is short enough to be self explanatory.

```
(defun endless/backup-display-property (invert &optional object)
  "Move the 'display property at POS to 'display-backup.
Only applies if display property is an image.
If INVERT is non-nil, move from 'display-backup to 'display
instead.
Optional OBJECT specifies the string or buffer. Nil means current
buffer."
  (let* ((inhibit-read-only t)
         (from (if invert 'display-backup 'display))
         (to (if invert 'display 'display-backup))
         (pos (point-min))
         left prop)
    (while (and pos (/= pos (point-max)))
      (if (get-text-property pos from object)
          (setq left pos)
        (setq left (next-single-property-change pos from object)))
      (if (or (null left) (= left (point-max)))
          (setq pos nil)
        (setq prop (get-text-property left from object))
        (setq pos (or (next-single-property-change left from object)
                      (point-max)))
        (when (eq (car prop) 'image)
          (add-text-properties left pos (list from nil to prop) object))))))
```

Please to let me know if it works! I only tested it on very simple webpages.

Comment: Beautiful, it works very well for me.

Comment: I used it a lot and wonder how can I hide the inline image and show the text by default?

Answer (score 8):

As of Emacs 25.1 you can pass an argument to `eww-reload` to load from the cache rather than the network. I'm using the following:

```
(defun my/eww-toggle-images ()
  "Toggle whether images are loaded and reload the current page fro cache."
  (interactive)
  (setq-local shr-inhibit-images (not shr-inhibit-images))
  (eww-reload t)
  (message "Images are now %s"
           (if shr-inhibit-images "off" "on")))

(define-key eww-mode-map (kbd "I") #'my/eww-toggle-images)
(define-key eww-link-keymap (kbd "I") #'my/eww-toggle-images)

;; minimal rendering by default
(setq-default shr-inhibit-images t)   ; toggle with `I`
(setq-default shr-use-fonts nil)      ; toggle with `F`
```

This disables images and proportional fonts by default. Font toggling is bound to `F` by default, so I'm using `I` for toggling images. (This replaces a default binding for `shr-insert-image`, but I've never used that.)

Comment: Any difference between using the `defvar` `shr-inhibit-images` and the `defcustom` `shr-blocked-images`?

Comment: I don’t think so. `inhibit` is a boolean and `blocked` is a regex, so you might use the regex to always block certain URLs while still using inhabit to toggle everything else on and off.

Comment: @glucas Thanks for this! I want to know what `eww-link-keymap` is; reading `*Help*` didn't help ;) Could you please explain what it is and why add a key binding to that too?

Comment: @legends2k That keymap applies when point is on a link in an eww buffer. That additional binding is probably not actually needed as Emacs will fall back to the mode map there anyway.

Comment: @legends2k Sorry, I was wrong just now. The additional binding is needed because eww has "I" bound to shr-insert-image in the eww-link-keymap by default, so I'm replacing that binding. If you use a different key that does not conflict with any eww defaults, you would only need to add it to the mode map.